# What does JreDisabled:java.security means if a cipher is disabled under Jetty logs

Tags: java, android, ssl, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to run Jetty server on an Android application with TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA but saw that it is not listed under enabled.

```
    private static final String[] suites = {
            "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    };

    SslContextFactory ctxFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    ctxFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(new String[0]);
    ctxFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(suites);
```

Below is the Jetty Dump log after starting the server:

```
   |       +- Protocol Selections
   |       |   +- Enabled (size=4)
   |       |   |   +- TLSv1
   |       |   |   +- TLSv1.1
   |       |   |   +- TLSv1.2
   |       |   |   +- TLSv1.3
   |       |   +- Disabled (size=0)
   |       +- Cipher Suite Selections
   |           +- Enabled (size=0)
   |           +- Disabled (size=25)
   |               +- SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security
   |               +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
   |               +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ConfigIncluded:NotSpecified
```

What does JreDisabled:java.security means? Does Jetty support this TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  cipher suite?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the JRE (or JDK) that you are running has that specific TLS Cipher Suite (or TLS Protocol) disabled in the configuration belonging to that JRE.

Example: on OpenJDK 11

```sh
$ grep -A2 tls.disabledAlgo $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```